# Cannot get web3.eth.sendTransaction() to work properly. The function does not fire

Tags: web3js, testrpc, myetherwallet, ethereumjs, rinkeby

I am creating this very simple program that sends ETH from one address to another. I am using *rinkeby.infura.io* to get FREE ether and for testing purposes.

My code seems to work fine because when I test it in testrpc on *http://localhost:8545* and using the dummy account addresses, everything works just perfectly fine. But when I change to real account addresses and change the HttpProvider to *https://rinkeby.infura.io/*, I get the below error:

> Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
>       at Object.InvalidResponse (D:\Documents\Projects\Eth\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\errors.js:38:16)
>       at HttpProvider.send (D:\Documents\Projects\Eth\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:91:22)
>       at RequestManager.send (D:\Documents\Projects\Eth\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:58:32)
>       at Eth.send [as sendTransaction] (D:\Documents\Projects\Eth\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\method.js:145:58)
>       at sendBalance (D:\Documents\Projects\Eth\routes\index.js:57:11)
>       at D:\Documents\Projects\Eth\routes\index.js:80:12
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Documents\Projects\Eth\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (D:\Documents\Projects\Eth\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (D:\Documents\Projects\Eth\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Documents\Projects\Eth\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

I noticed I forgot to include a callback function on the part of the code **web3.eth.sendTransaction({})**, so I changed it to something like **web3.eth.sendTransaction({}, function(err, hash){})**. It removed the Invalid JSON RPC error message, but it does not perform the entire ***sendTransaction()*** at all because I can see the balances were untouched.

Here is the output using the rinkeby.infura.io and with the callback function:

[image]

For your reference, below are two versions of my code: (1) with the callback function for ***sendTransaction()***, and (2) without the callback function

**(1) With Callback Function**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var util = require('ethereumjs-util');
var tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
try {
    var lightwallet = require('eth-lightwallet');
} catch (err) {
delete global._bitcore
    var lightwallet = require('eth-lightwallet');
}
var txutils = lightwallet.txutils;

var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/'));

function balance(addr) {
    var start = Date.now();
    var latestBalance = web3.eth.getBalance(addr, "latest");
    var nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addr, "latest");
    var end = Date.now();
    return nonce;
}

function showBalance(addr) {
    var start = Date.now();
    var latestBalance = web3.eth.getBalance(addr, "latest");
    var nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addr, "latest");
    var end = Date.now();
    var res = {
        "address": addr,
        "balance": latestBalance + " Wei / " + web3.fromWei(latestBalance).toString() + " ETH",
        "nonce": nonce.toString(),
        "timestamp": (end - start).toString() + "ms"
    }
    return res;
}

function sendBalance(_from, _to) {
    var nonce = balance(_from);
    var amount = 0.05;
    var rawTx = {
        nonce: web3.toHex(nonce),
        gasPrice: web3.toHex(10),
        gasLimit: web3.toHex(21000),
        to: _to,
        value: web3.toHex(amount * 1000000000),
        data: "",
        chainId: 1
    }

    var addFromPrivateKey = new Buffer('4ce80ef53f9c13e5d68737ff078e0660e803f87735fab9c79bf408335be8963d', 'hex');
    var transaction = new tx(rawTx);
    transaction.sign(addFromPrivateKey);
    var res ="";
    var serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex');
    web3.eth.sendTransaction({ 
        from: _from, 
        to: _to,
        value: web3.toWei(amount, "ether"),
        gas: rawTx.gasLimit,
        price: rawTx.gasPrice,
        nonce: rawTx.nonce
    }, function(error, hash){res = error;});
    var txLog = "";
    // web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx, function(err, result) {
    //  if(err) {
    //      txLog = err;
    //  } else {
    //      txLog = result;
    //  }
    // });
    res = "Status: " + res + " |||| from: " + _from + "\nsendValueETH: " + amount + "\nrawTx: " + JSON.stringify(rawTx, null, 4) + " " + txLog; 
    return res;
}

// Get Homepage
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var dti = sendBalance('0xa5d1274a05ab92e3830d81e0e4302498ccb5b22f', '0x6a1366a19b6dbb4d9fe4781f38538e9dc2ec0698');
    dto = showBalance('0xa5d1274a05ab92e3830d81e0e4302498ccb5b22f');
    dtt = showBalance('0x6a1366a19b6dbb4d9fe4781f38538e9dc2ec0698');

    data = {
        "dta": {
            "sender": dto,
            "recipient": dtt,
            "transaction": dti
        }
    }
    res.render('index', {data});
});


module.exports = router;
```

**(2) Without Callback Function**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var util = require('ethereumjs-util');
var tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
try {
    var lightwallet = require('eth-lightwallet');
} catch (err) {
delete global._bitcore
    var lightwallet = require('eth-lightwallet');
}
var txutils = lightwallet.txutils;

var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/'));

function balance(addr) {
    var start = Date.now();
    var latestBalance = web3.eth.getBalance(addr, "latest");
    var nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addr, "latest");
    var end = Date.now();
    return nonce;
}

function showBalance(addr) {
    var start = Date.now();
    var latestBalance = web3.eth.getBalance(addr, "latest");
    var nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addr, "latest");
    var end = Date.now();
    var res = {
        "address": addr,
        "balance": latestBalance + " Wei / " + web3.fromWei(latestBalance).toString() + " ETH",
        "nonce": nonce.toString(),
        "timestamp": (end - start).toString() + "ms"
    }
    return res;
}

function sendBalance(_from, _to) {
    var nonce = balance(_from);
    var amount = 0.05;
    var rawTx = {
        nonce: web3.toHex(nonce),
        gasPrice: web3.toHex(10),
        gasLimit: web3.toHex(21000),
        to: _to,
        value: web3.toHex(amount * 1000000000),
        data: "",
        chainId: 1
    }

    var addFromPrivateKey = new Buffer('4ce80ef53f9c13e5d68737ff078e0660e803f87735fab9c79bf408335be8963d', 'hex');
    var transaction = new tx(rawTx);
    transaction.sign(addFromPrivateKey);
    var res ="";
    var serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex');
    web3.eth.sendTransaction({ 
        from: _from, 
        to: _to,
        value: web3.toWei(amount, "ether"),
        gas: rawTx.gasLimit,
        price: rawTx.gasPrice,
        nonce: rawTx.nonce
    });
    var txLog = "";
    // web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx, function(err, result) {
    //  if(err) {
    //      txLog = err;
    //  } else {
    //      txLog = result;
    //  }
    // });
    res = "Status: " + res + " |||| from: " + _from + "\nsendValueETH: " + amount + "\nrawTx: " + JSON.stringify(rawTx, null, 4) + " " + txLog; 
    return res;
}

// Get Homepage
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var dti = sendBalance('0xa5d1274a05ab92e3830d81e0e4302498ccb5b22f', '0x6a1366a19b6dbb4d9fe4781f38538e9dc2ec0698');
    dto = showBalance('0xa5d1274a05ab92e3830d81e0e4302498ccb5b22f');
    dtt = showBalance('0x6a1366a19b6dbb4d9fe4781f38538e9dc2ec0698');

    data = {
        "dta": {
            "sender": dto,
            "recipient": dtt,
            "transaction": dti
        }
    }
    res.render('index', {data});
});


module.exports = router;
```

P.S. It's worth mentioning that those are sample private key and addresses only for presentation purposes here. And also, you may disregard anything about rawTx :)

Here is a sample successful output using testrpc:

[image]

Again, it works on testrpc, but not on rinkeby.infura. I think it definitely will not work on the real ethereum network too. I am new to ethereum and blockchain development. Any help i.e. solution to my issue, suggestions on my code, I would greatly appreciate it guys! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is still there. It just happens to not render as part of the result, after having included the callback function, because the `error` is set asynchronously. If you change `res = error` to `console.error(error)`, for example, you will be able to see it on the spot: `Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""`.

The reason for `Invalid JSON RPC response` is that *Infura* does not support the `sendTransaction` method, since it depends on account details.
According to the documentation **[1]**:

> INFURA supports a subset of Ethereum's JSON-RPC methods. Most of the
>   unsupported methods have to do with private keys.

In addition to reading back the error directly from `sendTransaction` callback, it is possible to use something like `curl` to make a request and confirm the method is indeed not available.
Example:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "eth_sendTransaction", "params": []}' \
    "https://rinkeby.infura.io/"
```

Outputs:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
[...]
```

This behavior is also documented:

> If you try to use a method that is not on this list, you will receive
>   a 405 Method Not Allowed HTTP response.

You should use opt to `sendRawTransaction` instead, which is in the provided code, as you mentioned, to send the already signed transaction data to *Infura*.

**[1]** https://github.com/INFURA/infura/blob/master/docs/source/index.html.md#supported-json-rpc-methods

Stay super!

/Javi